# pronoun usage with a preceeding a

Tags: pronouns

What pronouns would you use in the following sentence
John and Lou recognized a bear cub.  Replacing the proper nouns with a pronoun and then replace bear cub with a pronoun.

Comment: I think the assignment is just poorly worded and actually means you should replace "a bear cub" with a pronoun.

Comment: The only time you are likely to meet an article before a pronoun is in the question, "Is it a 'he' or a 'she'?"

Answer (score 1):

A bear cub could be made an "it". John and Lou could be a "they". I think the best way would be "They recognized it".